# Light color scheme for PowerShell in Windows Terminal

Tags: powershell, terminal

I'm one of the four people left who still likes light themes - I did dark for awhile, and I'm back to the light side.

In PowerShell in Windows Terminal, the built in light themes are unusable because the command is a really light yellow, and numbers are completely invisible. From what I can tell, that's not customizable in the options. I can change the yellows and it doesn't affect this.

Is there an option or theme or something that makes PowerShell look good with a light theme?

[image]

Here's Tango Light:

[image]

Comment: There are several light themes.   Which one are you using?  Tango Light seemed OK to me.

Comment: @John Added a screenshot of Tango Light - the "clear" is very light, and the "1234" is nearly invisible.

Comment: I will look around. I use Terminal in a window (so not large on the screen) and terminal black (main system is all Light (no dark mode) looks fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The built in light themes are unusable because the command is a really light yellow

You can override the colours by editing your PowerShell profile file (`profile.ps1`). For example I have my colours set to:

```
# Syntax highlighting colors

Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{
  Command            = 'Black'
  Number             = 'DarkGray'
  Member             = 'DarkGray'
  Operator           = 'DarkGray'
  Type               = 'DarkGray'
  Variable           = 'DarkGreen'
  Parameter          = 'DarkGreen'
  ContinuationPrompt = 'DarkGray'
  Default            = 'DarkGray'
}
 
# Logging / Progress colors
 
$p = $host.privatedata
$p.ErrorForegroundColor    = "Red"
$p.ErrorBackgroundColor    = "White"
$p.WarningForegroundColor  = "Yellow"
$p.WarningBackgroundColor  = "White"
$p.DebugForegroundColor    = "Yellow"
$p.DebugBackgroundColor    = "White"
$p.VerboseForegroundColor  = "Black"
$p.VerboseBackgroundColor  = "White"
$p.ProgressForegroundColor = "DarkGray"
$p.ProgressBackgroundColor = "White"
```

To locate your `profile.ps1` see [about Profiles - PowerShell | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2)

> **Token colors**
>
> To get an overview of your current color settings, you can use this
> command:
>
> ```
> Get-PSReadlineOption | Select *color
> ```

For more information on changing colours see [Change PowerShell console syntax highlighting colors of PSReadLine – 4sysops](https://4sysops.com/wiki/change-powershell-console-syntax-highlighting-colors-of-psreadline/)

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer of DavidPostill, beginning with PowerShell 7.2 you can also tune the colors of the output of ls. This is usually the one that really hurts the eyes in light mode. Executables and directories default colors are really difficult to read.

Following is an example setup, more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/using-light-theme?view=powershell-7.4)

```
# Configure the color of the ouput of ls
$PSStyle.FileInfo.Directory            = $PSStyle.Background.FromRgb(0x2f6aff) +
                                         $PSStyle.Foreground.BrightWhite

$PSStyle.FileInfo.Executable           = $PSStyle.Background.FromRgb(0x339933) +
                                         $PSStyle.Foreground.BrightWhite
```