# How do I change the background color for folders in PowerShell when invoking the "ls" command from WSL Interop?

Tags: command-line, bash, powershell, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed the `WslInterop` module and exposed several commands from WSL2.

I'm using `Import-WslCommand "apt", "cat", "awk", "nano", "find", "grep", "head", "less", "man", "sed", "seq", "ssh", "sudo", "tail", "touch", "ls"` in my profile.

Now, In my Bash shell, I have the following line:

```sh
# Changes the obnoxious colors of directories in ls -a
export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:ow=1;34:tw=1;34:"
```

This successfully removes the background colors of directories and makes `ls -a` output much more pleasant to the eye in bash (and bash only).

But when I run `ls -a --color=auto` in a PowerShell prompt, the background colors reappear:

[image]

Is there a way to modify or configure the `WslInterop` module and/or its configuration to make the same adjustment that I use in Bash? (
`export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:ow=1;34:tw=1;34:"`)

Where is WslInterop's commands sourcing their configuration? There is no `.bashrc` to configure.

Can somebody help?

Thanks!

Comment: Does [Light color scheme for PowerShell in Windows Terminal](https://superuser.com/a/1748972) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill No. PowerShell is invoking the `ls` command directly from WSL2 via the WslInterop module. This has nothing to do with PSReadLine. I already answered this question with the correct solution, but for some reason it was deleted? Did you delete the response?

Comment: There is no deleted answer showing - try answering again

Comment: @DavidPostill Added the answer. Sorry if I sounded accusatory, I was positive I added an answer to this question earlier. But I guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the author of [PowerShell WSL InterOP](https://github.com/mikebattista/PowerShell-WSL-Interop), Environment variables are supported by `$WslEnvironmentVariables`. And Default parameters are supported by `$WslDefaultParameterValues`.

So the solution I came across was to add the following lines to my PowerShell profile:

```
$PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'Ansi'
$WslDefaultParameterValues = @{}
$WslDefaultParameterValues["ls"] = '--color=always'
$WslEnvironmentVariables = @{}
$WslEnvironmentVariables["LS_COLORS"] = "rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36::ow=1;34:tw=1;34:"
```

By populating `$WslEnvironmentVariables["LS_COLORS"]` with the same values as Bash, I was able to get the same color highlighting as if I was in a Bash shell. I also added `$WslDefaultParameterValues["ls"] = '--color=always'` to ensure that color is always displayed for the `ls` command.

All of these additions fixed my problem entirely.

Hope this helps someone!